# Combined key's pressed with ActionBinding

Tags: java, swing, key-bindings, key-events

I got this code to identify if the user press the ctrl + A button:

```
    mPanel.getInputMap().put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_A, InputEvent.CTRL_DOWN_MASK), "ALL");
    mPanel.getActionMap().put("ALL", new AbstractAction() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
          System.out.println("All");
        }
    });
```

unfortunality the method is never entered.

Currently I dont know what I am missing.

Could you help me?

Comment: `getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW)`. Currently with what you have, the component needs to be focused.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's three `InputMap` for the compoent

- [`JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW)
- [`JComponent.WHEN_FOCUSED`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#WHEN_FOCUSED)
- [`JComponent.WHEN_ANCESTOR_OF_FOCUSED_COMPONENT`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#WHEN_ANCESTOR_OF_FOCUSED_COMPONENT)

When just calling `getInputMap` without an argument, it implicitly implies

```
getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_FOCUSED)
```

So you should use `getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW)`

- See more at [How to use Key Bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html)